# Borrowed value does not last long enough when defining operators for references

Tags: operator-overloading, rust, lifetime

Why does the borrow checker not like last add operation in this code:

```
use std::ops::Add;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Vector(f64, f64, f64);

impl<'r> Add for &'r Vector {
    type Output = Vector;

    fn add(self, _rhs: &'r Vector) -> Vector {
        Vector(self.0 + _rhs.0, self.1 + _rhs.1, self.2 + _rhs.2)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v1 = &Vector(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
    let v2 = &Vector(13.0, 12.0, 11.0);

    println!("{:?}", v2.add(v1)); // Ok
    println!("{:?}", v1.add(v2)); // Ok

    println!("{:?}", v2 + v1); // Ok
    println!("{:?}", v1 + v2); // error: borrowed value does not live long enough
}
```

Commenting out the last `println!` makes this code work, which seems like a compiler bug.

Answer (score 4):

You have this code:

```
impl<'r> Add for &'r Vector {
    type Output = Vector;

    fn add(self, _rhs: &'r Vector) -> Vector {
        Vector(self.0 + _rhs.0, self.1 + _rhs.1, self.2 + _rhs.2)
    }
}
```

Which, when expanded out, looks a bit like this:

```
impl<'r> Add<&'r Vector> for &'r Vector {
    type Output = Vector;

    fn add(self: &'r Vector, _rhs: &'r Vector) -> Vector {
        Vector(self.0 + _rhs.0, self.1 + _rhs.1, self.2 + _rhs.2)
    }
}
```

That is, you have implemented the trait for two references that can be constrained to have overlapping lifetimes, and the value of `'r` will be the intersection of those lifetimes. If you allow adding references of two *distinct lifetimes*, it works:

```
impl<'r, 's> Add<&'s Vector> for &'r Vector {
    type Output = Vector;

    fn add(self, rhs: &'s Vector) -> Vector {
        Vector(self.0 + rhs.0, self.1 + rhs.1, self.2 + rhs.2)
    }
}
```

I'l admit that I don't fully understand why calling `add` directly would be any different though. And as far as I can see, if it's able to create an intersecting lifetime for one direction, I'd expect it to be able to go the other direction.

---

Additionally, you should **not** use `_rhs` as the variable name here. The preceding underscore is notation for "this variable is unused", but you definitely use it.

Comment: Thanks for comprehensive answer. I think rust uses some "workaround" for direct calls. When the operator form used that "workaround" does not apply.

Comment: @aSpex FWIW, I don't think this is actually an *answer* to your question; it's just a workaround. I'd hope that someone more knowledgable could actually say why this happens or confirm that it's a bug or missing implementation. That would be a much better answer.